# if the wsa:Address and wsa:Action was wrong according to wsdl and xsd's then what the to do?

Tags: soap, cxf

If the wsa:Address and wsa:Action was wrong according to wsdl and xsd's then whether we have to process that request or what? 
I have search for it,but not get it.